# Oracle Instant Client 64-bit "Unable to connect, SQLState=" Windows Server 2012

Tags: oracle, odbc

I have installed the Oracle 12.2 Instant Client ODBC 32 & 64 bit drivers and required software (VS C++ redist 2013 32 & 64 bit) on Windows Server 2012. I can create a connection and connect successfully via the 32 bit driver but when using the 64 bit driver I get the error below. I have turned on tracing at the trace log is below. Using the 32bit driver is not an option nor is any other method ODP.net as we are using 3rd party software. The server itself is Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition  12.2.0.1.0

[image]

```
odbcad32        e40-129c    ENTER SQLAllocEnv 
        HENV *              0x000000BA3CB98940
odbcad32        e40-129c    EXIT  SQLAllocEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV *              0x000000BA3CB98940 ( 0x000000BA3CFCEA50)
odbcad32        e40-129c    ENTER SQLAllocConnect 
        HENV                0x000000BA3CFCEA50
        HDBC *              0x000000BA3CB98948
odbcad32        e40-129c    EXIT  SQLAllocConnect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV                0x000000BA3CFCEA50
        HDBC *              0x000000BA3CB98948 ( 0x000000BA3CFCEB30)
odbcad32        e40-129c    ENTER SQLDriverConnectW 
        HDBC                0x000000BA3CFCEB30
        HWND                0x00000000000304CE
        WCHAR *             0x00007FF855AFADB8 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x00007FF855AFADB8 
        SWORD                       -3 
        SWORD *             0x0000000000000000
        UWORD                        1 <SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE>
odbcad32        e40-129c    EXIT  SQLDriverConnectW  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        HDBC                0x000000BA3CFCEB30
        HWND                0x00000000000304CE
        WCHAR *             0x00007FF855AFADB8 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x00007FF855AFADB8 
        SWORD                       -3 
        SWORD *             0x0000000000000000
        UWORD                        1 <SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE>
odbcad32        e40-129c    ENTER SQLGetDiagRecW 
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
        SQLHANDLE           0x000000BA3CFCEB30
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x000000BA3CB98830
        SQLINTEGER *        0x000000BA3CB988F0
        SQLWCHAR *          0x000000BA40865140 
        SQLSMALLINT               1024 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x000000BA3CB988F4
odbcad32        e40-129c    EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 100 (SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND)
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
        SQLHANDLE           0x000000BA3CFCEB30
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x000000BA3CB98830
        SQLINTEGER *        0x000000BA3CB988F0
        SQLWCHAR *          0x000000BA40865140 
        SQLSMALLINT               1024 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x000000BA3CB988F4
odbcad32        e40-129c    ENTER SQLDisconnect 
        HDBC                0x000000BA3CFCEB30
odbcad32        e40-129c    EXIT  SQLDisconnect  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        HDBC                0x000000BA3CFCEB30
DIAG [08003] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Connection not open (0) 
odbcad32        e40-129c    ENTER SQLFreeConnect 
        HDBC                0x000000BA3CFCEB30

odbcad32        e40-129c    EXIT  SQLFreeConnect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HDBC                0x000000BA3CFCEB30
odbcad32        e40-129c    ENTER SQLFreeEnv 
        HENV                0x000000BA3CFCEA50

odbcad32        e40-129c    EXIT  SQLFreeEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV                0x000000BA3CFCEA50
```

Comment: ...and you do know that there are two odbcad32.exe? One is in `C:\Windows\System32` directory (64-Bit) and the other one is to be found in the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` directory (32-Bit). You might have to configure your settings in the appropriate location.

Comment: Yes, in control panel under administrative tools there are 2 ODBC options, one for 32 and 64 which is what I have been testing with.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the 32-Bit components and trying again? You might have a mismatch of the 32-Bit and 64-Bit environments. (registry, environment variables, VS C++ config, etc.)

Comment: Are you using separate Oracle Home directories for the 32 and 64 bit drivers, or did you install them to the same home directory?

Comment: 64 bit ODBC driver requires also 64 bit Oracle Client. In case you need both at the same time (e.g. for testing) follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100 Note, there is no 64 bit ODBC driver from Microsoft, you must use the Oracle driver.